# Session on Play Game Service Unity(C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I can login successfully on my playstore account. Here is my code so verifying if the user login earlier or not.

```
public void Start(){

    //client configuration creation
    PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().Build();

    //enable debugging
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;

    //Initialize and activate the platform
    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate ();

    //Authenticate if the user logged in earlier or its his/her first log in.
    if (Social.localUser.authenticated) {
        authStatus.text = "Welcome back : " + Social.localUser.userName;

    } else {
        authStatus.text = "Not yet Sign In";
    }
}
```

So my question is: It seems like my code above doesnt work cause if i logged in for the very first time then close the app and re open the app again it will still need to relogin which is not appropriate and very wrong right .

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Programmer my question is that it doesn't have a session sir . If i logged in then close the app and then re open it still i need to login and that's not what i wanted. it actually like my authentication doesnt work

Comment: @WillyDavidJr Thank you Mr.

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

Comment: @Nico Can you point out where should i look there because i've been reading it for like the whole time sir.

Comment: There is a complete tutorial on the whole page on how to use that plugin and integrate it in your app sir. Read it carefully and try to understand the workflow. Read [configure the project](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity#configure-your-game) and [sign in](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity#sign-in) also [savegame in google services](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity#configuration--initialization-play-game-services) if that is also what you need

Comment: @Nico It is actually logging in now the problem is that when i close the app and re open it i still need to login its like it doesn't read the last login